# Volver a la misma posición Y al cerrar un popup

Tags: html, css

Al hacer clic en un `<a href="#image">` se abre una imagen popup. Esta imagen a su vez tiene un `<a href="#">` para volver a la página principal. El problema es que al volver salta a la parte superior de la página (cuadrado rojo en el ejemplo) y preferiría que lo haga en la misma posición en la que está el botón.

```css
* {overflow:visible;}


div {background:lightgray; height:200px; width:200px; margin: 0 auto 20px;}

div:first-child {background:red;}

.popup {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    padding-top: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
    background: #747691;
    z-index: 510;
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0;
   vertical-align: top;
}

.popup:target {
display: block;
-webkit-animation-name: fadein 0, 2s;
animation-name: fadein;
animation-duration: 0.2s;
background-color: rgb(116, 118, 145);
background-color: rgba(116, 118, 145, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<a href="#image">Click</a>

<div id="image" class="popup">
    <a href="#"><img id="popupImage" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/eb/Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Evitando usar JS?

Comment: Si. La respuesta con JS ya la tengo, quisiera saber si es posible con los enlaces href.

Comment: Una alternativa es el _hack del checkbox_... Solo que parecer que tiene problemas de accesibilidad. En ese caso no trabajás con anclas (`<a>`), sino con un label vinculado a un checkbox oculto. Suele ser utilizado en menús. Todo es vía CSS.

Comment: Suena a parche :-/

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la [API de Popover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Popover_API/Using)

En el botón que abre el popup debes colocar `opovertarget="ID_DE_POPUP"` y en el popup `popover="auto"` para convertir al `div` en popup

Ejemplo:

```css
* {overflow:visible;}


div {background:lightgray; height:200px; width:200px; margin: 0 auto 20px;}

div:first-child {background:red;}

[popover] {
  position: fixed;
  inset: 0;
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0.25em;
  overflow: auto;
  color: CanvasText;
  background-color: Canvas;
  padding:0;
}
::backdrop {
  background-color: rgba(116, 118, 145, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<button popovertarget="image">Click</button>

<div id="image" class="popup" popover="auto" >
    <img id="popupImage" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/eb/Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg">
</div>
```

Además existe el atributo [popoverTargetAction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/popoverTargetAction) que permite setear la acción (abrir/cerrar) de un botón

Comment: Hmmmm... No funciona correctamente en Firefox (la imagen se abre directamente, y no se puede cerrar)

Comment: @padaleiana En efecto, así lo indica la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Popover_API#browser_compatibility), en firefox se encuentra en estado experimental. Firefox es un navegador que debe morir, es un lastre, no tiene la capacidad de desarrollo para avanzar en nuevas mejoras según avanza la especificación